# how to save the modifications on the server

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I would like to implement a download counter so that everytimes an user click on the download button, the download number value in the form increments.

Here is my button declaration:

```
<a id='id' onclick='Increment()' href='/folder/"+rfilename+"' download></a>
```

Here is the label I want modify :

```
<label id = 'dlCounter'><b> Number of Downloads : 0</b></label>
```

Here is my function :

```
  <script>
  function Increment()
  {
    var downloadCounter = $("#dlCounter").text(); //get current value
    var number = downloadCounter.replace( /^\D+/g, ''); //remove non digits
    var number = parseInt(number); 
    number = number+1;
    var string = "Number of Downloads : "+number;
    $("#dlCounter").text(string);
    $("#dlCounter").css("font-weight","Bold");

   //send modifications to the server
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '{$action}',
        data: $('#dlCounter').serialize(),
        success: function(d) {
          console.log("Successful", d);
        },
      error: function() {
        console.log("Unsuccessful");
      }
   });

  }
</script>
```

The counter is actually incrementing but it is only in local, once I close the windows and go back to the form, the value reset to 0, how can I send my modifications to the server at every click?

I thought the ajax part would do it but It is not working. Yet when I look at my console, I get the successful message followed by my whole form code (the d variable).

what am I missing?

I assume It would be preferable to store this value in a database, but everything is saved in the form.

Comment: You can not provide it permanently without the use of any database.

Comment: Can I not just save my updated form at every click on the button?

Comment: Are you actually saving the value to a database? Also, you have the label hardcoded at being 0 so even if you are saving it, you need to load the current value on page load as well.

Comment: no the value is not saved to a database, the value 0 is hardcoded when I am saving the form in my createTopic function, I thought I could modify it later on for every user clicks

Comment: @rilent You can do it. You need to use a server-side language. Ex : php,asp, java, phyton, etc...

Comment: @rilent You need a database to store the updated data (no. of clicks). Ajax is used to submit a form without reloading the page. You need to use a server in order to save the current state of the form and then update accordingly.